# Xvfb on debian not installing properly from apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, xvfb

I try to install xfvb for headless firefox and selenium tests, but after installing by:

`apt-get install xvfb`

I got only those files on server (search by *xvfb*):

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run
/usr/share/doc/xvfb
/usr/share/man/man1/xvfb-run.1.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xvfb.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xvfb.md5sums
/var/cache/apt/archives/xvfb_2%3a1.7.7-14_i386.deb
```

As you can see, no `xvfb` executable in `/usr/bin/`

Using Debian `2.6.32-042stab055.12`

Comment: `dpkg -L xvfb` would give you the full list of files provided by the package. You would probably come to DerfK's conclusion then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual executable name is `/usr/bin/Xvfb` with the capital X.

Comment: The command worked for years with a lower case X and suddenly stopped working. Thanks for saving me a few hair-pulling hours debugging to find out what's wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Debian **stable** and apt-get reports a successful install then you can be almost 99.99% sure it was successful. In other words, a mistake is most likely something you forgot to check, or overlooked or another end user error. In fact i can't remember a problem ever with a Debian stable package installing incorrectly.

This is not gripe about the user, but a compliment towards Debian's excellent packaging system and stability.